# Unable to log into uwsgi console

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, logging, uwsgi

so I'm running python with django and uwsgi

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /path1
wsgi-file = path/wsgi.py
processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
autoreload=1
```

but doing print() from python won't print out anything....also tried logging.warning('something') but something wont get outputted

how do I log something out to the console in uwsgi?

Comment: show me how do you launch uwsgi? what command (with options) you using? Output of your uwsgi app probably is in /var/log/uwsgi/yourapp.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` will generally not work in production. For logging to work you need to configure logging by adding something like this to the settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/django.log',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

See [Configuring logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) for more information.